# Get Oracle View Definition with limited control

Tags: oracle, plsql

My issue is I have a custom SQL runner hitting an Oracle, readonly db.

I want to get the definition of a view.

```
 select TEXT
 FROM all_VIEWS
 where VIEW_NAME  = '<view_name>';
```

This returns me limited text. A max of so many characters, maybe 100. All the views are longer than this.

The help file I found showed adding the 'set long 10000' before to capture the entire field I guess.

```
SQL> set long 10000

SQL> select TEXT
  2  FROM all_VIEWS
  3  where VIEW_NAME  = '<view_name>';
```

I don't have access to hit the `set long 10000` since I'm running through another window. Is there another way to get the full definition with my limited ability?

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error in the question. There is no WHERE clause, but AND keyword has been used. Correct query should be 

  select TEXT
  FROM all_VIEWS
  WHERE VIEW_NAME  = '<view_name>';

Comment: @Mandar syntax fixed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is the LONG column containing the view definition.

You may use the DBMS_METADATA package to get the view text as a CLOB

```
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL ('VIEW','view_name','owner') from dual;
```

Comment: @IstvanDevai Maybe, but I have ATM no idea how, sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately, you need privileged access for this to work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026068/dbms-metadata-get-ddl-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Using @Marmite's suggestion of `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL`, and assuming the tool you're using only lets you retrieve 100 chars at a time, the following should retrieve your complete view:

```
SELECT view_name, LEVEL "Line No", 
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(view_clob, 100 ,1 + (LEVEL-1)*100) line_text FROM (
    SELECT view_name, owner, 
    DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('VIEW', view_name, owner) view_clob 
    FROM all_views WHERE view_name = '<view_name>'
) CONNECT BY LEVEL <= CEIL(LENGTHB(view_clob)/100) ORDER BY LEVEL;
```

Comment: ORA-22998: CLOB or NCLOB in multibyte character set not supported

Comment: @vulkanino:  Really?  That is the exact error message that the `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR` should avoid.