# Can I export objects in another user's schema through SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

If someone has granted me `select` privileges on objects in their schema, how can I export their objects (such as tables and sequences) and data using SQL Developer?

I have tried using the the Data Export wizard but that only lets me export my own objects and data. Is there a way to export from someone else's schema instead?

Comment: `can I export all his data`. Define export.

Comment: define "all" his data. Metadata, table defs etc, or only rows/columns of tables. Good luck.

Comment: Have you tried, through tools->database export?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov export tables and what is inside them (primary keys, columns..), export sequences too.

Comment: @AlexPoole i can only export the database that my user created through this way, i can't export what other user created and give me access

Comment: If anybody cares - I filed my displeasure with the closing of this question here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332661/who-gets-to-vote-to-close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can export other users' object from the Tools->Database Export wizard.

After you have chosen the connection, whether to include DDL and/or data, and which types to export you get a dialog to specify the objects to export.

[image]

If you click the More button you can then choose the schema (i.e. owner; your colleague in this case), and can search for objects in that schema that you want to include in the export.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, this really helped.

Comment: Important: Even though you can select objects in this view, it doesn't mean that they will get exported. SQL Developer will silently fail for objects where your user needs the SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026068/dbms-metadata-get-ddl-not-working. Really bad UX in my opinion.