# How to view DDL of oracle view in Sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl

I have created a view in Oracle which has about 15,000 lines (Most of them are case statements) in two databases. 
I am able to view the DDL of the view in the SQL tab of the Sql developer in one database. However, I am unable to view it in the second database.

I get the below few lines only in the SQL tab instead of the full view definition:

```
-- Unable to render VIEW DDL for object MY_VIEW with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.
CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW
AS
```

I have given all types of grants for the view to public with no success. I have read that we can use GET_DDL function but I'd prefer to view in the SQL tab. Can anyone please help to view the DDL or is it any difference in the two databases?

Comment: "However, I am unable to view it in the second database." >> Second  schema or second database ? Thanks!

Comment: Also, have you tried to run dbms_metadata.get_ddl ? Thanks!

Comment: if you use the view in the second database, it works?

Comment: @VBoka: Second database; I am not able to get through get_ddl. It says "does not exist"

Comment: @gsalem: I can use select statement on it and view it through the Data tab.

Comment: @Arun please can you give me the entire error not only "does not exist" ? Thanks!

Comment: this is usually a privilege issue, the SQL page also uses dbms_metadata.get_ddl, so if that's not working, neither will the SQL page

Comment: I believe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026068/dbms-metadata-get-ddl-not-working

Comment: @VBoka You're right. This seems like a privilege issue since I could view the DDL in DEV environment. This is the entire error which worked on first database but not in second.



`ORA-31603: object "MY_VIEW" of type VIEW not found in schema "MY_SCHEMA"

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 5805

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 8344

ORA-06512: at line 1

31603. 00000 -  "object \"%s\" of type %s not found in schema \"%s\""

*Cause:    The specified object was not found in the database.

*Action:   Correct the object specification and try the call again.`

Comment: Check the link, test it as it says's there and see... Best of luck!